# Numpy Error "ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2."

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I am a complete newbie in ML with scikit-learn
I just wanted this to work after a lot of time that i spent on learning what ML was its types and so on.

```py
from sklearn import tree
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

age = df.Age.to_list()
age = np.array(age).reshape(-1,1)

inc = df.Income.to_list()
inc = np.array(inc).reshape(-1,1)

stud = df.Student.to_list()
stud = np.array(stud).reshape(-1,1)

buy = df.Buy.to_list()
buy = np.array(buy).reshape(-1,1)

X = [age,inc,stud]
y = [[buy]]

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(X, y)
'''
Income:
1 - high
2 - medium
3 - low

Student:
1 - yes
2 - no

'''
age = 34
inc = 1
stud = 2


pred = clf.predict(age,ince,stud)

print(pred)
```

But i get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:\Huzefa\Desktop\ML.py",
>   line 23, in 
>       clf = clf.fit(X, y)   File "C:\Users\Huzefa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree_classes.py",
>   line 894, in fit
>       X_idx_sorted=X_idx_sorted)   File "C:\Users\Huzefa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree_classes.py",
>   line 158, in fit
>       check_y_params))   File "C:\Users\Huzefa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py",
>   line 429, in _validate_data
>       X = check_array(X, **check_X_params)   File "C:\Users\Huzefa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py",
>   line 73, in inner_f
>       return f(**kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Huzefa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py",
>   line 642, in check_array
>       % (array.ndim, estimator_name)) ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.

if i could just correct my script to make it work i will be motivated to continue further with ML
All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try - `pred = clf.predict([age,ince,stud])`

Comment: Thanks for your answer bro! but it wont work. Still the same error

Comment: `buy` is already a list, so when you define `y` do it as `y = [buy]` or `y = np.array(buy)`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're defining your X and y seems overcomplicated to me, is there a specific reason behind that choice?
You could also do the following:

```
X = df[["Age","Income","Student"]]
y = df.Buy
```

Also, by doing

```
clf = clf.fit(X, y)
```

you're training your decision tree on all the data available. If this is a train dataset and you have a test dataset stored elsewhere, that's okay; if not, you need to split the data first, so you can train the model AND test the efficiency of said training. `train_test_split` is a useful function for this.

Comment: can you help me with the "train_test_split" function? Actually i am pretty new to ML and am struggling with the basics

Comment: @HuzefaUsama You're welcome! If you have new questions I encourage you to make other posts, it'll make it easier for people to anwer you.